# Getting PHP parse error regarding required drop-down menu item selection in basic contact form

Tags: php, contact-form, parse-error

I'm creating a basic contact form with a few required fields and a required selection from a drop-down menu. The fill-in fields are working correctly, however the drop-down menu selection requirement is causing a parse error.

I commented out any instances of the drop-down menu requirement to find that the error is gone. So the error has something to do with the drop-down menu selection. According to the error logs, the problem is in line 49. I tried rewriting that line a few times without much success.

Is the error caused by something specifically in line 49 or is elsewhere in my syntax?

This is my first time writing PHP, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EMAIL and SUBJECT
$email_to = "xxx@xxx.com";

$email_subject = "Test Form Dev";


function died($error) {
    // ERROR CODE
    echo "We apologize for the inconvenience, but there were error(s) found with your form submission. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and correct the error(s).<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// VALIDATION EXPECTED DATA EXISTS
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['inquiry']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // REQUIRED
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // REQUIRED
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // REQUIRED
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // NOT REQUIRED
$inquiry_type = $_POST['inquiry']; // REQUIRED
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // REQUIRED

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$inquiry_exp = 'Charter, Media, Broker,'; // drop-down menu options
if(strlen($inquiry) < 1) {
$error_message .= 'Please select inquiry type.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Inquiry Type: ".clean_string($inquiry)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// CREATE EMAIL HEADERS
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- RETURN MESSAGE (HTML): SUCCESSFUL FORM SUBMISSION -->

<p>Thank-you message goes here.</p>

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Edit: I'm building this form in a MAMP environment. I've read elsewhere that I need to create an htaccess file, but is that necessary for a local dev?

Edit 2: After looking around other forums, I learned that I have to break down the dropdown menu items individually in PHP. I got that accomplished, but am still getting Parse:syntax errors on line 98 (the last line) stating "unexpected $end". However, I cannot get the menu selection to populate in the generated email nor figure out what specifically is causing the error. I originally fixed my code according to the error log without success.

Here's my updated code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EMAIL and SUBJECT
$email_to = "xxx@xxx.com";

$email_subject = "XXX";


function died($error) {
    // ERROR CODE
    echo "We apologize for the inconvenience, but there were error(s) found with your form submission. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and correct the error(s).<br /><br />";
    die();
 }

// VALIDATION EXPECTED DATA EXISTS
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['inquiry']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // REQUIRED
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // REQUIRED
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // REQUIRED
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // NOT REQUIRED
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // REQUIRED
$inquiry = $_POST['inquiry'];

if( empty( $inquiry ) || $inquiry == "null" )
    // If there isn't a value for the dropdown, or they've selected the option
    // that reads "Please select one" then return an error
    die( "Please select your reason for inquiring on the drop-down menu." );

switch( $inquiry ){

    case "Broker" : die(); break;
    case "Press" : die(); break;
    case "Charter" : die(); break;
    default : die();

}

}

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Inquiry Type: ".clean_string($inquiry)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// CREATE EMAIL HEADERS
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Can anyone provide any insight to what's causing the form to error out?

Comment: Which line is line 49? What was the error?

Comment: line 49 is which one exactly.. ?

Comment: This code has no syntax error

Answer (score 1):

CHange `if(strlen($inquiry) < 1){ ...` on line 49 to `if(strlen($inquiry_type) < 1)`
Also change `clean_string($inquiry)` to `clean_string($inquiry_type)` on line 69

Comment: I corrected for the mismatched tags and made them all consistent, but am still getting an error. Could it be caused by the field text/symbol requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared a `$inquiry` variable so the following lines will report errors:

```
if(strlen($inquiry) < 1) {
$email_message .= "Inquiry Type: ".clean_string($inquiry)."\n";
```

You do have a `$inquiry_type` variable so this is probably a typo.

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo. I made the variable consistent throughout the code and re-tested, but am still getting an error. I checked the error log, but am not seeing anything (the last recorded error was from yesterday).

I'm thinking the error might be caused by the field text/symbol requirements?